# Mostrar datos especificos de un objeto en un arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Para un proyecto debo hacer una concesionaria de autos. Dentro de las funcionalidades de la concesionaria debo mostrar la lista de los autos que hay en stock. Pero al crear el objeto para agregarlo al arrayList se crea con otra cantidad de datos que no hay que mostrar en la lista. Mi duda era como podría hacer para mostrar estos datos específicos. Pensé que con un for each podría ser posible. Adjunto un diagrama con las clases para entendimiento de mi idea. [image: pequeño diagrama para mostrar las clases y como se componen]

yo al crear por ejemplo un objeto 'Sedan' inevitablemente heredo todo de las clases padre.

```
case "VER LISTA":
        for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.size(); i++) {        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, vehiculos.get(i) + "\n" + "su posicion es " + i);
        }
        break;
```

Esto es como lo tenia ahora antes de darme cuenta de que tendría que hacer que muestre solo los datos específicos. Para cerrar re pregunto: Como puedo hacer para que al crear un objeto "Sedan" en un arrayList al momento de invocarlo por consola me muestre solo aquellos atributos de la clase vehículos.

Comment: objeto y propiedades; tienes que hacer accesible para sedan el método obtener vehículo y que te permita accede a las propiedades de vehículo. normalmente yo implemento setter y getter para estos temas ...

Comment: fíjate si esto te ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25109709/17161735

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Gracias! yo pensaba hacerlo sin una cantidad masiva de getters y setters pero me veo que va a tener que ser asi :(. gracias por la ayuda y el link

Comment: la verdad esa es la manera correcta de programar de forma orientada a objetos si en realidad deseas implementar objetos; puedes preguntarle a tu papa, este ha sido un tema amplio de discusión en el chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 1):

Y no te sale mas a cuenta, crear una bbdd con los modelos y un campo que sea *boolean* donde diga que si hay en stock un *true* y si no un *false*,
a la hora de hacer el dao y el método los guardas todos con un *getter* an *setter*, finalmente cuando recuperes con el típico *for* los rescatas de la siguiente manera:

```
for(Coches co: coches){
    List<coches> disponibles = new ArrayList<coches>();
    if (co.nombrecolumna == true )
        disponibles.add(co)
}
return disponibles;
```